# eMMC Jedec Backward Compatibility

Tags: memory

I'm working on a new design based on a Xilinx FPGA.

I'd like to use some eMMC devices but the FPGA controller supports JEDEC up to 4.51.

Nowadays, some eMMC devices are JEDEC 5.0 or 5.1 compliant and they add some great fonctionalities. But I'd like to know a eMMC 5.1 is backward compatible with a controller that supports 4.51 then I could use such a device with my FPGA.

Comment: A quick (and cursory) search showed this question, such as this one: https://discuss.96boards.org/t/emmc-4-5-vs-emmc-5-0/3390

Comment: So basically it is backward compatible and you just need to leave pins related to newest features unconnected ?